# extending CSS style in JAVAFX

Tags: css, javafx

I' m trying to use CSS in JAVAFX application. Is there a way in the CSS file to  make use of some kind of inheritance?
For example I have one style called "redline":

```css
.redline{
    -fx-stroke:red;
    -fx-stroke-width:5px;
}
```

Can I create a second style "greenline":

```css
.greenline{
    -fx-stroke:green;
}
```

in a way that it inherits from "redline". Say, something like:

```
greenline extends redline
```

so that the "green" lines have a strokewidth of 5px?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a make a more specific selector available. You could e.g. add a style class:

Add the style class `line` to all lines and then also add the `red` or `blue` style classes to the lines that should get those colors.

### Example

#### Java Code

```
Line redLine = ...
redLine.getStyleClass().add("line");
Line blueLine = ...
blueLine.getStyleClass().add("line");
Line blackLine = ...
blackLine.getStyleClass().add("line");

// add color related classes
redLine.getStyleClass().add("red");
blueLine.getStyleClass().add("blue");

...
```

#### CSS

```css
.line {
    -fx-stroke: black; /* define standard line color */
    -fx-stroke-width: 5px;
}

.line.blue { /* rules for nodes that have style classes line AND blue */
    -fx-stroke: blue;
}

.line.red { /* rules for nodes that have style classes line AND red */
    -fx-stroke: red;
}
```

In CSS more specific rules will always overwrite properties of less specific rules. In this case `.line` is less specific than `.line.blue` and `.line.red` since the former selector contains only a single class instead of 2.

---

**Note:** There is inheritance in CSS, but properties are inherited from the parent in the scene, not from the base class in the java code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using the method .setStyle(). I didn't knew about the .getStyleClass().add(). Everything is perfect now!!!