# JavaFX CSS style inheritance

Tags: css, javafx

Given the following:

```
.base_arc
{
  -fx-stroke: #000000;
}

.child_arc
{
  -fx-stroke-line-cap: BUTT;
}
```

How can I make `.child_arc` inherit the `-fx-stroke` value, such that everyone who uses `.child_arc` gets the values in `.base_arc` as well? I am looking to avoid manually applying my base styles to every element, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310053/extending-css-style-in-javafx).

Comment: Is something like `.base_arc, .child_arc { /* common styles */ } .child_arc { /* specific styles */ }` what you're looking for?

Comment: This does indeed work. So for each style I need to list all children that will use it. Not really inheritance, but it's close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and simple answer is Slaw's comment (which may not use CSS inheritance at all):

```
.base_arc, .child_arc { /* common styles */ } 
.child_arc { /* specific styles */ }
```

A longer answer, discussing CSS inheritance and its relationship with object-oriented inheritance is below.

**Background on CSS inheritance vs object-oriented inheritance**

[CSS inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) is not like the [object oriented inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) that Java has.

Instead, CSS inheritance is based upon the node position in the [scene graph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/scene-graph-tutorial/scenegraph.htm#JFXSG107).  Child nodes can inherit CSS properties from their parents (if the CSS property is inheritable).  Inheritance is based upon position in the scene graph, not on the Java class type hierarchy.  This is documented in the [JavaFX CSS documentation on inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introinheritance).

**Applying CSS inheritance to your example**

*Create CSS rules for the parent node*

Let's say you have a `Pane` in which you draw your arcs, and you set the style `drawing-pane` on it.  If you have the following css rule:

```
.drawing-pane Arc { 
    -fx-stroke: black; 
}
```

, then all arcs drawn in the pane would be black.  I didn't test that, but it is my understanding of how it works.

The `Arc` rule is a [CSS type selector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph), so `.drawing-pane Arc` will select any arcs which have been drawn in the drawing pane.

*Create CSS rules for specific types of child nodes*

Now, to differentiate different arcs to have different styles, you need to have an additional, more specific, CSS rule which applies the specific style.

So, if you create the following rule:

```
.drawing-pane .child-arc {
    -fx-stroke-line-cap: BUTT;
}
```

, then all of the arcs which are added to the drawing pane which also have the style class `child-arc` assigned to then will get a butt cap.  They will also have a black stroke as the previous `drawing-pane Arc` rule still also applies to them (through CSS inheritance).

*Associate your nodes with appropriate CSS rules*

There are various ways you could associate the `child-arc` class with an arc, for example with a factory method:

```
Arc createChildArc() {
    Arc arc = new Arc();
    arc.getStyleCass().add("child-arc");
}
```

Or via inheritance by setting the style in a constructor:

```
public class ChildArc extends Arc {
    public ChildArc() {
        getStyleClass().add("child-arc");
    }
}
```

*Using CSS type selectors rather than class selectors*

Note: it is possible to use a type selector (no `.` prefix and refers to a simple, non-package prefixed Java class name) rather than a css class selector (uses a `.` prefix), so you could do:

```
public class ChildArc extends Arc {}
```

and have CSS as:

```
.drawing-pane ChildArc {
    -fx-stroke-line-cap: BUTT;
}
```

But, in general, the css style classes are probably a bit more flexible and also in more common usage then the type selectors, so I'd probably just stick with the class selectors.

---

I'm not really sure if this is the answer you really wanted, but it is my understanding of one way to solve the problem you currently have.

I think what you are really looking for is the info on SASS outlined below, though, in general it isn't how the problem would be solved when using straight CSS without additional tooling.

**Using SASS to add object-oriented inheritance to CSS**

If you use a pre-processor such as [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/guide) on your css style sheets, you can bring a lot more features (from SASS) into your style sheets.  The features that SASS supports include mix-ins and extensions for CSS styles.  So SASS makes CSS more object oriented in how it defines its styling rules, by allowing object-oriented style inheritance of style information.

Whether you want to invest the time and assume the complexity to learn SASS and implement it into your build chain is up to you.  Personally, for myself, I wouldn't use SASS unless I were writing an awful lot of CSS, which I just don't do.

The standard default css for JavaFX (modena.css), is large, complex and feature rich, and does not make use of SASS style features in its implementation.  Studying modena.css is the best way to learn JavaFX CSS best usage practices and principles.  If SASS isn't required for something as complicated as modena.css, then it is unlikely to be really necessary for the CSS stylesheets you create for your application.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer, thank you. Coming from a WPF background, it doesn't seem trivial to do what I want with native CSS, setting up base styles whose individual properties can be overridden easily and/or applying them with minimal duplication of code. Need to do more reading!